# Ускорение записи новых значений в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, webgl

Я пополняю массив большим количеством новых значений, для отрисовки объектов на canvas'е, это занимает не мало времени. Собственно вопрос: можно ли ускорить этот процесс/другой способ сохранения данных?
Код:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>-</title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="5000">HTML5 Canvas is not supported by your browser</canvas>

        <script src="./engine.js"></script>
        <script id="main"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                document.querySelector('#main').src = "./main.js";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
'use strict';

function draw() {
    console.time('execution time');

    console.time('write time');
    for(let y = 0; y < mapY; y++) {
        for(let x = 0; x < mapX; x++) {
            addCell(x, y, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // add cell to draw list (positionX, positionY, color0, color1, color2, color3, rotateAngle)
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd('write time');

    console.time('render time');
    render(); // draw all from draw list
    console.timeEnd('render time');

    console.timeEnd('execution time');
}

const atlas = new Image();

const scale = 5;
const lineWidth = 0;

const mapX = Math.floor(canvas.width / scale);
const mapY = Math.floor(canvas.height / scale);

setupGL(scale, lineWidth, [0, 0, 0, 1]);

console.log('Map size: ' + mapX + 'x' + mapY);

atlas.src = './atlas.png';
atlas.onload = function() {
    addTexture(gl, atlas);

    draw();
}

window.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
        clearList(); // clear draw list

        draw(); // draw
    }
}
```

engine.js:

```
'use strict';

// ========== shaders ==========
const vsSource =
`#version 300 es

layout(location=0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
layout(location=2) in vec2 aOffset;
layout(location=3) in float aTexID;
layout(location=4) in vec4 aColor;
layout(location=5) in float aAngle;
layout(location=6) in float aTexTransperent;
layout(location=7) in float aSize;
layout(location=8) in float aLineWidth;
layout(location=9) in vec2 aResolution;

out vec4 vColor;
out vec2 vTexCoord;
out float vTexID;
out float vTexTransperent;

vec2 rotate(float angle) {
    float c = cos(angle);
    float s = sin(angle);

    return vec2(aPosition.x * c - aPosition.y * s + 0.5, aPosition.x * s + aPosition.y * c + 0.5);
}

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4((((rotate(radians(aAngle)) + aOffset) * aSize + aOffset * aLineWidth) / aResolution * 2.0 - 1.0) * vec2(1.0, -1.0), 0.0, 1.0);

    vColor = aColor;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
    vTexID = aTexID;
    vTexTransperent = aTexTransperent;
}`;

const fsSource =
`#version 300 es

precision lowp float;

in vec4 vColor;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
in float vTexID;
in float vTexTransperent;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    if (vTexTransperent > 0.0) {
        fragColor = texture(uTexture, (vTexCoord + vec2(mod(vTexID, 6.0), floor(vTexID / 6.0))) * 32.0 / 128.0) * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, vTexTransperent);
    }
    else {
        fragColor = vColor;
    }
}`;
// =========================

// ========== functions ==========
function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    if (gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) return shader;
    console.log(type == gl.VERTEX_SHADER? 'VERTEX SHADER' : 'FRAGMENT SHADER', gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource) {
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource));
    gl.attachShader(program, createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource));
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    if (gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        gl.useProgram(program);
        return program
    };
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

function addTexture(gl, image) {
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    return texture;
}

function setupGL(size, lineWidth, color) {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    gl.clearColor(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    clearList();

    gl.vertexAttrib1f(7, size); // set size
    gl.vertexAttrib1f(8, lineWidth); // set line width
    gl.vertexAttrib2f(9, canvas.width, canvas.height); // set canvas resolution in WebGL
}

function clearList() { // clear draw list
    transformData.length = 0;
}

function addCell(offsetX, offsetY, color0, color1, color2, color3, angle, id) { // add cell to draw list
    transformData.push(offsetX, offsetY, id, color0, color1, color2, color3, angle, 0, offsetX, offsetY, id, color0, color1, color2, color3, angle, 1);
}

function render() { // draw all form draw list
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, transformBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(transformData), gl.STATIC_DRAW); // upload data to buffer

    // set data to attributes
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(2, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 36, 0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(3, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 36, 8);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(4, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 36, 12);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(5, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 36, 28);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(6, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 36, 32);

    gl.drawArraysInstanced(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6, transformData.length / 9);
}
// =========================

// ========== init ==========
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }) || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl2', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }); // get GL context
if (!gl) alert('WebGL Context init failed');
const program = createProgram(gl, vsSource, fsSource); // create shader program

const modelData = new Float32Array([
//  position        texCoord
    -0.5, -0.5,     0, 0,
     0.5, -0.5,     1, 0,
    -0.5,  0.5,     0, 1,
    -0.5,  0.5,     0, 1,
     0.5, -0.5,     1, 0,
     0.5,  0.5,     1, 1,
]);
const transformData = []; // offset; color; angle; texTransperent; texOffset

const modelBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
const transformBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

gl.enable(gl.BLEND); // enable transperency
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
//gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelBuffer); 
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, modelData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
// set primitives vertecies
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0); 
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);

// say webgl, that this attributes must change 1 per instance
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
gl.vertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(2);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(3);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(4);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(5);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(6);
// =========================
```

Запись в массив в *main.js => draw()* & *engine.js => addCell()*

Comment: Нужен полный рабочий пример.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy добавил.

Comment: Зачем на каждый пиксел канвы две одинаковые точки?

Comment: 1-й полигон для заднего фона, 2-й для спрайта, если я понял о чём Вы.

Comment: Если задний фон статичный, не надо его каждый кадр создавать. Если спрайт не занимает весь экран, не надо его на весь экран растягивать. Статичный фон вообще надо натянуть на один квад или два треугольника и забыть про него. На две меняющиеся координаты вы создаёте семь неизменных значений. Всё разнести по отдельным спискам.

Comment: Фон не статичный. Он показывает есть ли сигнал в клеточке.

Comment: Чтобы рисовать много разноцветных точек придуманы текстуры. Не надо каждую точку изображать своим треугольником. Надо взять два больших треугольника и натянуть на них текстуру.